# How to change the class of an element, when clicking a anchor tag link with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, anchor

Well, how can I change the class (active/non_active) of an element with the ID that a anchor tag link activates with jquery?

HTML:

```
<a href="#element1">Show element 1</a>
<a href="#element2">Show element 2</a>

<div id="element1" class="active"><p>Element 1</p></div>
<div id="element2" class="non_active"><p>Element 2</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.active{ visibility:visible; }
.non_active{ visibility:hidden; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<a class="accordion-header" href="#element1">Show element 1</a>
<a class="accordion-header" href="#element2">Show element 2</a>
<div id="element1" class="element active">
    <p>Element 1</p>
</div>
<div id="element2" class="element">
    <p>Element 2</p>
</div>
```

then

```
var $els = $('.element');
$els.not('.active').hide()
$(".accordion-header").on("click", function (e) {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')).show()
    $els.not($target).hide()
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3J9WK/)

Comment: @PepijnGieles see the second demo there are changes in css, html and script

Comment: Is `preventDefault` required in this case given that anchor points an element within the same page? I don't see any difference even without that.

Answer (score 2):

You can just take the `href` from the clicked element and use that as the selector:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $("div.active").toggleClass("active non-active");
  $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass("active non-active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $(a).removeClass("active");// Nake all the existing links inactive by removing class active
   $(this).addClass("active"); //then make current link as active
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `non_active` class even necessary? I would omit that, and then with jQuery I would do the following (expanded a bit for readability):

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default <a> behaviour

    var $elm = $(this), // store the clicked element
        activateElement = $elm.attr('href'); // get the value of the href attribute

    $('.active').removeClass('active'); // remove currently active element

    $(activateElement).addClass('active');  // set clicked element to active by removing non_active
});
```

**CSS:**

```
div{ visibility: hidden; }
.active{ visibility:visible; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax8Hz/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.active').removeClass('active'); // remove existing active
  $(id).addClass('active'); // set current link as active
//or
//$(id).attr('class','active'); // set current link as active

});
```